# Does someone have a digitalized version of the Chabad's table of interruptions in Prayer?

Tags: tefilla

Almost all Chabad sidurim has a table in the beginning with the places of the tefila and where you can or can't respond amen, baruch hu uvaruch shmo etc depending on where you are in the prayer. Very useful when you get late for the tefila!!!

But i don't have a chabad sidur at home. Does someone have a similar table online or digitalized? I could't find it something like that searching in google!

Comment: Just ask your rabbi all the questions and write down his answers. That'll be more useful to you then the table of a publisher who isn't your rabbi

Comment: Doubtless http://hebrewbooks.org has Chabad prayer books. Try searching in the title field for `תהלת`.

Comment: @DoubleAA True. But, last time I asked a Chaba"d rabbi, he told me, "I don't recall all the places, offhand. Where's that Tehillat Hashem siddur?" I think an easier solution would be to ask a Chaba"d rav if he can spare one of the shul's siddurim.

Comment: @DanF If your rabbi is a chabad rabbi, then fine, but for most Jews you shouldn't just follow chabad rulings because they did a good job printing a lot of them in an organized chart.

Answer (score 5):

The chart is taken from [Kuntrus Dinei Hefsek BeTfilla from Harav Yosef Yitzchak Eidelman](http://hebrewbooks.org/30485).

The chart itself is on page 8: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30485&pgnum=8

Answer (score 3):

Here's a scan of the table from my own Kehot Siddur Tehillat Hashem:

[image: Siddur Tehillat Hashem Annontated English Edition (Kehot Publishers) Table of Permitted/Prohibited Interruptions During Prayer]

Comment: Sorry the scan isn't too clear.